# Communicating between two docker services in docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker, json-server

I just started working with docker-compose and am stuck in communication between the two services.

I have 2 services: angular and json. I want to get some data from json to angular app. As far as I understood, services should be able to reach each other by using the servicename as hostname.

Unfortunately, angular cant reach json on http://json-server:3000.

What am doing wrong? Is it even possible to make http requests between services?

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  json-server:
    image: json-server-image:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: json-server
    hostname: json-server
  angular:
    image: angular-image:latest
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    links:
      - json-server
    container_name: angular
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `hostname: json-server` line ?

Comment: yes, i try, result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Your Angular code doesn't run in Docker.  The container named `angular` probably provides an HTTP service that can provide the actual Angular code, but the code itself runs in the browser, outside of Docker.  The browser doesn't know anything about Docker networking and can't directly access the network stack.

From the browser's point of view, you need to access the back-end service using the host name of the system it's running on, and the externally published (first) `ports:` number.  If the browser and containers are running on the same system, the host name could be `localhost`, so `http://localhost:3000/api/...`.

A standard technique for avoiding needing to actually know the host name is to run a reverse proxy, such as an `nginx` container, that can forward to both containers.  That would use the Docker-internal hostnames and the internal port numbers in its configuration, `http://json-server:3000` and `http://angular:80`.  From the browser point of view both would be on the same host and port, and a path-only relative URL `/api/...` would go to that same server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  json-server:
    image: json-server-image:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: json-server
    hostname: json-server
    networks:
      - some-net
  angular:
    image: angular-image:latest
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    container_name: angular
    networks:
      - some-net

networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Basicaly, the following code create a user defined docker bridge network.

```
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Adding the following lines to each service links them together in the same network.

```
networks:
      - some-net
```

Must Read: [User defined bridge v/s default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks)

Comment: Compose will create all of this setup for you by default; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  The network is named `default` and is attached to containers if no explicit `networks:` are specified.  You don't need `container_name:` or `hostname:` either.